# Bug: managed library expressions are freed prematurely during evaluation

Tags: evaluation, librarylink

I believe I have run into a bug with managed library expressions and garbage collection behavior. In the example below, adapted from the documentation for `CreateManagedLibraryExpression`, the managed library expression will be freed before the ID is passed to `setInstanceState`, resulting in an error:

```
setInstanceState = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo_managed","setInstanceState",{Integer, {Integer, 1}},"Void"];
setInstanceState[ManagedLibraryExpressionID[CreateManagedLibraryExpression["LCG",randomLCG]],{1664525,1013904223,2^32,0}]
```

Results in `LibraryFunctionError["LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR", 6]`

Assigning to a symbol keeps the managed library expression alive, so the below works as expected:

```
setInstanceState = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo_managed","setInstanceState",{Integer, {Integer, 1}},"Void"];
g=CreateManagedLibraryExpression["LCG",randomLCG];
setInstanceState[ManagedLibraryExpressionID[g],{1664525,1013904223,2^32,0}]
```

This is quite a problem for me. I create many managed library expressions on the fly during evaluation to manage OOP C++ object instances in an otherwise functional-style WL codebase. In my codebase, the `CreateManagedLibraryExpression` will typically be assigned to a local symbol in a `Module[]` or `With[]`, not some long lived symbol in a notebook, and the aggressive garbage collection of managed library instances frees the instance before downstream code gets a chance to run.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a known workaround?

Comment: I'd recommend to use Szabolcs Horvat's `LTemplate` package to manage C++ objects. You can get it from here: https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate

Comment: I am indeed using LTemplate, it greatly simplifies the interop between WL and C++. Unfortunately, LTemplate does not prevent this bug. The managed library expression returned from LTemplate`Make[] will similarly be freed too soon by the GC during evaluation.